# How to move all the repositories from github account to antoher github account?

Tags: git, github, github-for-windows

I am currently using a github enterprise in which I got the account from my school.

I did not know that other users cannot access my github site. So I am trying to move all the repositories to a normal github account.

Does anyone know how to do this?

OR is there any way that I can turn my enterprise acocunt into a normal github account?